# Status Bar is overlapping in Tab Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tablayout, windowinsets

The Tab Layout is overlapping with the status bar, I found a couple of threads having the same thing, but the solution seems to be adding "fitsSystemWindows" and I've already set it in my XML layout, the strange thing is I have more tabs like this and they seem to work perfectly.

[image]

This is my XML layout, any inputs would be helpful.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@id/root"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp" />




        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_bg"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:orientation="vertical">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnfilter"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_amount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="6000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorToday"
                        android:textSize="39dp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@id/title_amount"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/title_amount"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/title_amount"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_orange_big"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView9" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/btnfilter"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
                        android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                        android:text="TODAY"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorToday"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

                    android:weightSum="3">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/title_amount_yesterday"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_rupee_white"
                            android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                            android:text="5000"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                            android:text="Yesterday"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                            android:text="Yesterday"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/title_amount_persent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_percentage"
                            android:text="20%"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="percentage"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/center1"
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkPink"
                            />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/week_amount"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_rupee_black"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                                android:text="25,000"/>


                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:text="this week"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/mtd_amount"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_rupee_black"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                                android:text="2.5 L"/>


                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:text="MTD"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/arrow1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:padding="0dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_pink_transaction"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorDarkPink"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/center2"
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
                            />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/month_amount"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_rupee_black"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                                android:text="25,000"/>


                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:text="this week"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center2"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/avg_month_amount"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_rupee_black"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                                android:text="7,000"/>


                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:text="Avg. Monthly"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/arrow2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:padding="0dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_green_transaction"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>



        <include layout="@layout/barchart"></include>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/performance_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">


                <include layout="@layout/performer_details"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"></include>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">


                <include layout="@layout/lest_performer_details"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"></include>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



        <include layout="@layout/piechart"></include>





    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: change to full screen theme

Comment: @VivekMishra what do you mean ??

Comment: try by switching to full screen theme. Google for it and put that theme in styles.xml and then apply that theme to your activity in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows` to your `LinearLayout` to adjust view layout based on system windows such as the status bar. If `true`, adjusts the padding of this view to leave space for the system windows.

*Will only take effect if this view is in a non-embedded activity.*

Also you could try update your v21/styles.xml

```
 <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

and make sure

```
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

If this won't resolve your issue, apply next line to the application theme:

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

**That's not recommended approach**, but it would help you investigate problem.

If it's not root view, make sure `android:fitsSystemWindows` is `true` for the view that's located higher in hierarchy.

Comment: did that too,still the same :(

Comment: added the entire layout

Comment: changed the styles,still the same

Comment: @bob make sure you've updated v21/styles.xml, but not default styles.xml

Comment: @sam Ok, how you're using this layout? If it's not root view, make sure `android:fitsSystemWindows` is `true` for the view that's located higher in hierarchy

Comment: ,yep that solved,adding it to the Viewpager did the trick :D,thanks a lot